# WCF RIA Services - should it be used for ALL remote functionality?

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services, ria

I'm planning on doing a simple Silverlight (and/or ASP.NET MVC) application that will be using a lot of "update rows in a database" functionality, and RIA Services seems to be the perfect choice for communication between the client and the server/database.

But I'm also thinking of implementing some sort of chat/instant messager into the same client. Can I implement this type of "non-data" functionality through RIA services (in a way that isn't too ugly) ? If not; what would be a good way to implement it? And wouldn't it be a bad idea to have several different types of communication channels (if one of the links disconnects, but not the other, etc.) ?

Answer (score 2):

> And wouldn't it be a bad idea to have several different types of communication channels (if one of the links disconnects, but not the other, etc.) ?

Addressing this part of your question. I think you should use the most appropriate technology for each aspect. RIA Services are asynchronous so they may be suitable for a chat application, but I'd verify they offer the performance you need. Don't be afraid to mix and match technologies.

One benefit of having different links is that you've got a backup communication method if your main link goes down. You could use it to push status messages (for example) or use it as way for your users to let you know of problems with the main application.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with ChrisF on that part.

You can read a lot more about WCF RIA Services on http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/riaservices/. There are several of videos and articles about WCF RIA Services and how to implement them.